# Custom User-Created RSS Feed

Tags: categories, rss

I have a WordPress site with nearly 10k articles and 90 categories. I'd like to be able to give our visitors the ability to select a number of categories from which a custom RSS feed would be generated for use in RSS automated email marketing (MailChimp). I've searched but haven't really found a plugin or solution.

Part two of this would be - is it possible to choose individual articles throughout the site to generate this feed?